# Unit Testing gwt-dispatch

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, junit, guice

I'm trying to write some unit tests for a gwt-dispatch service with JUnit. I'm getting the following error when stepping through the test with my debugger:

> Error in custom provider, com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException: Cannot access scoped object. Either we are not currently inside an HTTP Servlet request, or you may have forgotten to apply com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter as a servlet filter for this request.

I'm going to simplify the code a bit here -- hopefully I'm not stripping out anything necessary.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import net.customware.gwt.dispatch.client.standard.StandardDispatchService;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;
...

public class LoggedInServiceTest extends TestCase {

Injector i;
StandardDispatchService service;

protected com.google.inject.Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule(),
            new TestServletModule(),
            new ActionsHandlerModule(),
            new TestDispatchModule(),
            new OpenIdGuiceModule());

}

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    i = getInjector();
    service = i.getInstance(StandardDispatchService.class);
}

public void testNotLoggedIn() {
    try {
        GetProjectsResult result = (GetProjectsResult) service.execute(new GetProjectsAction());
        result.getSizeOfResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail();
    }
}
}
```

The service request is indeed supposed to be going through a GuiceFilter, and it looks like that filter is not being set.

Any ideas on what other setup needs to be done to register the filter?

Comment: Some stylistic suggestions in your test. 

1. setUp should be protected and call `super.setUp()` before doing anything (`TestCase.setUp()` does nothing, but if you change the base class, you could have problems).

2. Instead of catching Exception in your test and calling `fail()`, change your test method to declare that it throws `Exception`. If a test throws an exception, it automatically fails.

Comment: Thanks. The test is actually supposed to verify that the proper exception is thrown -- but you're right that the simplified code I posted isn't exactly pretty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is just what it states. You are trying to access a scoped object, but you are not currently in the scope. Most likely, your test is asking the injector for a `RequestScoped` object or an object that has a `RequestScoped` object in the injection dependency tree, but the test didn't do anything to enter the scope.

Binding the `GuiceFilter` in the test doesn't help, because your test isn't trying to send an `HttpServletRequest` through `GuiceFilter` to a servlet.

The best option would be to unit test your code. Create your classes in isolation, injecting mocks.

Assuming you want to do some kind of integration test, you have three options:

1. Have your test install a test module that called `bindScope(RequestScoped.class, new FakeScope)`. The `FakeScope` class would implement `Scope` and have methods to enter and exit the scope. You may have to "seed" the scope with fake implementations of objects you depend on. See the Guice [CustomScopes wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes). This is the best option for integration tests, IMHO
2. Use `ServletScopes.scopeRequest` ([Javadoc](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/servlet/ServletScopes.html)) to run part of the test code inside of a simulated request scope. This gets a bit ugly since you need to pass a `Callable`.
3. Do a full end-to-end test. Start your server and send it requests using Selenium. It's really hard to get good coverage this way, so I would leave this to things that you really need a browser to test.

Things might get a bit messy if the class you are testing depends indirectly on `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse`. These classes can be challenging to setup correctly. Most of your classes should not depend on the servlet classes directly or indirectly. If that is not the case, you are either doing something wrong or you need to find a good action framework that allows you have most of your code not depend on these classes.

Here's an example of approach 1, using `SimpleScope` from the Guice [CustomScopes wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes):

```
public class LoggedInServiceTest extends TestCase {
  private final Provider<StandardDispatchService> serviceProvider;
  private final SimpleScope fakeRequestScope = new SimpleScope();
  private final HttpServletRequest request = new FakeHttpServletRequest();

  protected Injector createInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new FakeRequestScopeModule(),
            new LoggedInServiceModule();
  }

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    Injector injector = createInjector();
    scope.enter();
    serviceProvider = injector.getProvider(StandardDispatchService.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    fakeRequestScope.exit()
    super.tearDown();
  }

  public void testNotLoggedIn() {
    fakeRequestScope.enter();
    // fill in values of request
    fakeRequestScope.seed(FakeHttpServletRequest.class, request);

    StandardDispatchService service = serviceProvider.get();
    GetProjectsAction action = new GetProjectsAction();
    try {
        service.execute(action);
        fail();
    } catch (NotLoggedInException expected) {
    }
  }

  private class FakeRequestScopeModule extends AbstractModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(RequestScoped.class, fakeRequestScope);
      bind(HttpServletRequest.class)
          .to(FakeHttpServletRequest.class)
          .in(RequestScoped.class)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The class I'm ultimately testing depends on HttpServletRequest/HttpSession via @Inject Provider<HttpServletRequest>. Is there any way to get around the NullPointerException it throws when calling .get() on the injected Provider?

Comment: You have to seed the HttpServletRequest into the scope. I added a code example.

Comment: Which version of Guice is this written against? I'm noticing that methods like the bind() in FakeRequestScopeModule seem to be moved to bindScope(), etc. Even after those changes I see errors like: No implementation for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest was bound.

Comment: I used the latest Guice API docs, but these methods have been around for as long as I've used Guice. `bindScope()` is for binding a `Scope` object to a binding annotation, while `bind()` is for binding classes and interfaces to implementations. It would help if you would update your question with the complete stacktrace. I'll update the answer a bit more.

Comment: Since `HttpServletRequest` is an interface, some module needs to provide a binding for that interface. Since `HttpServetRequest` is bound as `RequestScoped`, some module needs associate that annotation to a `Scope` object, so Guice knows when to create a request and when to use a cached request. I believe in the live application, `ServletModule` does both. I updated my code so `FakeRequestScopeModule` does both. You will need to provide a `FakeHttpServletRequest` implementation. As I said, it's better to have your objects not depend on the servlet code so you don't have to do all this work.

Comment: Good luck! If you study the above code, it becomes clear that modules are another possible injection point. If the class you are testing does not directly depend on `HttpServletRequest` then perhaps you setup a test module that lets you fake out the direct or indirect dependencies of your class. You can use `Modules.override()` to replace bindings in a production module with bindings in a test module.

Answer (score 0):

Write an AppSession interface and two implementations: HttpAppSession and MockAppSession. 
Make your server-side handlers depend on AppSession and not on HttpSession directly.

- Use Guice to inject HttpSession into HttpAppSession. That's the one you'll use in production, and for actually running your app. within a real servlet container.
- The MockAppSession should not depend on HttpSession, nor HttpServletRequest, nor any other Guice Http scope. That's the one you'll use during testing.

Now, your Guice module should inject an AppSession implementation as follows:

```
bind(AppSession.class).to(MockAppSession.class)
bind(MockAppSession.class).in(Singleton.class)
```

That'll sort you out.